# Font Scale Problem on Some Characters

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling, characters

I am editing a template of OverLeaf, everything is well however, there is a weird problem with the font.

The character "8" seems bigger with "\small" and "\footnotesize" like in the picture above.

[image]

What is the root cause? And how can I  make "8" smaller?

I've found the reason. This difference comes from its default design. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. Like, what font is this? How did you set it? What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using the web-based editor of OverLeaf. The main font is set to "Carlito" by the template.

Comment: the font uses old style numbers by default, use `\usepackage[lining]{carlito}` to get lining numbers.